# Table border lines/separate editing

Tags: html, css

I am working on an HTML/CSS project for my school but have run into a problem. On one of my pages I have 3 tables which I want to edit with CSS separately.
I've tried to put class in all of the tables but it still only takes the commands of the second table. Am I supposed to put class in all of the TRs and TDs too?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.tabel1 {
  border-color: purple;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}
.tabel2,
tr,
td {
  width: 350px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tabel3 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: purple;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: purple;
  box-shadow: 15px 6px 10px purple;
}
.tr1 {
  background-color: purple;
}
.tr2 {
  background-color: #9370DB;
}
.tr3 {
  background-color: purple;
}
.tr4 {
  background-color: #9370DB;
}
.tr5 {
  background-color: purple;
}
.tr6 {
  background-color: #9370DB;
}
.tr7 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabel1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Film-Favo's</strong>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<table class="tabel2" align="center">
  <tr class="tr1">
    <td>Film</td>
    <td>Regisseur</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tr2">
    <td>Film 1</td>
    <td>Regisseur 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tr3">
    <td>De noorderlingen</td>
    <td>Ales van warmerdam</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tr4">
    <td>Film 3</td>
    <td>Regisseur 3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tr5">
    <td>Film 4</td>
    <td>Regisseur 4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tr6">
    <td>Film 5</td>
    <td>Regisseur 5</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tr7">
    <td>Film 6</td>
    <td>Regisseur 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<table align="center" class="tabel3">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#EE82EE">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate.</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: can you post your html.

Comment: Did you misspell "table" in your HTML to match? There's nothing wrong with your CSS that we can tell without seeing your markup as well.

Comment: I just checkt it, it should work the class is right in both html and css                (i can upload my html too if you want to have a look at it)

Comment: Just post the table markup. We don't need the entire document. Also, fundamental programming sense indicates that you should be indenting properly. Use any of the plethora of auto-indenting editors to get that done.

Comment: You don't close 3rd table with `</table`> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the tr, td specification, your tables will be styled differently.  Your CSS should apply to the `table`, not to the rows or cells.

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/46dxof6f/).

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.tabel1 {
  border-color: purple;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.tabel2 {
  width: 350px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tabel3 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: purple;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: purple;
  box-shadow: 15px 6px 10px purple;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="tabel1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="tabel2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="tabel3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Result**

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious likely problem is that you've applied identical styles to `table2`, *all* `tr` elements, and *all* `td` elements with this rule:

```
.tabel2,
tr,
td {}
```

Do some study of descendant selectors and maybe try this:

```
.table2,
.tabel2 tr,
.table2 td {}
```

Somehow I doubt that's what you really want, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```